# Sleep for X milliseconds or on thread signal?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I want to sleep for X amount of time UNLESS a thread tells me to wake up. In the example below I want to sleep for either 10 milliseconds (1/100 of a second) OR until foo has 2000 items. Whicheever comes first. How do I do this? I made up the functions

MainThread:

```
pthread_sleep_fn(10000, some_cond_var)  
printf("%d items has been processed", foo.items.count())
```

Thread:

```
while(true)
    auto result = read_data()
    foo.items.add(result)
    if(foo.items.count()>2000)
        pthread_wake_up(some_cond_var)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait for a condition with timeout, use [`pthread_cond_timedwait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html).